# Getting the list of files changed from a commit in perforce

Tags: ant, hudson, perforce

Is there a way, in Hudson, of getting the list of files from a p4 change list and passing it to an ant build script ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to just trigger your Ant build script if a check-in is made to Perforce ?  If so, that's straightforward; use the [Perforce plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Perforce+Plugin).

Comment: No,that id did, i want the list of files affected by a commit in the SCM, so I can pass it to a ant script(which has a checkstyle task)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to parse them out of the change list that Hudson generates.  I don't know of any way to get it from the p4 plugin, although I think it would be useful information also.

Try something like this:

```
wget ${BUILD_URL}/changes -O - > changes.txt
```